# Breaking out a single page jquery mobile app, but then compiling it as one page? Any ideas on how to do this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been working with JQM a quite awhile now - and as many of you know it really shines when all of the page structures are in one page. This becomes quite a little maintenance issue if multiple people are working on the same file. So I was thinking what if there was a way similar to how I use less to run a compile of seperate .jqm files and merge them into one page structure.

Has anyone ever done this?

For those that have used less. I do something like this for my CSS files

layout.less
pages.less

Then I have one  app.less that essentially I run through less compiler and it spits out my nicely formatted CSS from the layout.less and page.less

Comment: With all the code being in separate files you loose a lot of the functionality of JQM. That's why if you use JQM it makes sense to put it all in one page as that is how it was designed to work place. Grunt may work I'll have to give it at try and see.

Answer (score 0):

We use [**Grunt**](http://gruntjs.com/) for JS compilation, looking through their plugins I see a plugin titled **"contrib-stylus Compile LESS files to CSS."** Well anyways if you haven't heard of Grunt it seems like the new way to add scripting to your environments and can do a lot of cool things.

On a separate note what's wrong with multi-page jQM projects? Less initial load, AJAX loading of subsequent pages is nice and if you put all your JS in one place it's not that hard to manage.